# Rails DB isn't populating with data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a substantial database, however when I recloned my repo and reloaded the database I am now receiving zero data from the tables. I ran the following code in my console, but I can't make sense of it, nor why it has happened, I've often recloned my repo and never had this issue, can anyone make sense of this?:

```
[12] pry(main)> Rails.configuration.database_configuration["development"]["database"]
=> "pair_development"
[13] pry(main)> Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
=> {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
 "encoding"=>"unicode",
 "pool"=>5,
 "timeout"=>5000,
 "username"=>"",
 "password"=>"",
 "database"=>"pair_development",
 "host"=>"",
 "port"=>"5432"}
[14] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
=> "pair_development"


➜  pair git:(sandbox-alpha) bin/rails console ...
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:260:in `resolve_symbol_connection': '../..' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "default_with_url", "development", "test", "production", "staging", "demo", "cucumber", "pair_history_development", "pair_history_test", "pair_history_default_with_url", "pair_history_staging", "pair_history_demo", "pair_history_production", "pair_jobs_development", "pair_jobs_test", "pair_jobs_default_with_url", "pair_jobs_staging", "pair_jobs_demo", "pair_jobs_production"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
        from /Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:241:in `resolve_connection'
        from /Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:143:in `resolve'
        from /Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:57:in `establish_connection'
```

My local DB is configured via my settings.local.yml as follows:

```
database: pair_development
file_storage:
  use_this_config: "YES"
  case_file_files:
    ......
```

Comment: `config.eager_load is set to nil`. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly. Have you looked what the value of that is?  What is your rails env?

Comment: @dbugger Updated all of those and zero change. It's in a development env

Comment: "pair_development" is not your list of available databases, `"default", "default_with_url", "development", "test", "production", "staging", "demo", "cucumber", "pair_history_development", "pair_history_test", "pair_history_default_with_url", "pair_history_staging", "pair_history_demo", "pair_history_production", "pair_jobs_development", "pair_jobs_test", "pair_jobs_default_with_url", "pair_jobs_staging", "pair_jobs_demo", "pair_jobs_production"`